# vb.net specilized/overloaded generics

Tags: vb.net, generics, overloading, specialization

I tend to loath repetition in code, so when I come across a problem where the only different is types I tend to use generics. Coming from a C++ background I find vb.net's version to be rather frustrating, I know C++ has template specialization and I guess vb.net does not
so what I have is a set of routines that do the exact same code regardless of type being passed.

something like this

```
Public Sub decision(Of T)(ByVal a As T, ByVal b As Integer)
  If b > 10 then
    gt(a)
  Else
    lt(a)
  End If
End Sub
```

I am only ever passing two types to routine, Strings and Integers and what those routines do with string differs from what it does with integers.

```
Public Sub gt(ByVal a As String)
Public Sub gt(ByVal a As Integer)

Public Sub lt(ByVal a As String)
Public Sub lt(ByVal a As Integer)
```

This is where I get frustrated with vb.net vs C++, AFAIK, C++ would check the types at compile time and only against what types are sent to decision. However, in vb.net I get an error that type T cannot be converted to String or Integer

```
Error   3   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'gt' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub gt(a As String)': Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'String'.
    'Public Sub gt(a As Integer)': Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
```

I tried constraints `Public Sub decision(Of T As {String, Integer})(ByVal a As T, ByVal b As Integer)` but constraints need to be Inheritable classes  so neither String, nor Integer can be used.

My Next Solution was to add a generic versions of `gt` and `lt`:

```
Public Sub lt(Of T)(ByVal a As T)
  Debug.Fail("Not Implemented")
End Sub

Public Sub lt(Of T)(ByVal a As T)
  Debug.Fail("Not Implemented")
End Sub
```

And hey! no more compile errors however the only routine that gets called is the generic version of `gt` and `lt`. Which I guess makes sense in light of the previous cannot convert errors. I've encountered this issue before where there are non-generic overloads of a generic routine, I could not find a solution then, and I cannot find a solution now.

Is there something I am missing that would make this type of overloading possible?

Edit: a complete working example

```
Module Module1
   Sub Main()

      decision(1, 5)
      decision(1, 10)
      decision("hello world", 5)
      decision("hello world", 10)

   End Sub


   Public Sub decision(Of T)(ByVal a As T, ByVal b As Integer)
      If b > 10 Then
         gt(a)
      Else
         lt(a)
      End If
   End Sub

   Public Sub gt(ByVal a As String)
      Debug.WriteLine(" gt string:  " + a)
   End Sub
   Public Sub gt(ByVal a As Integer)
      Debug.WriteLine(" gt integer: " + a.ToString)
   End Sub

   Public Sub lt(ByVal a As String)
      Debug.WriteLine(" lt string: " + a)
   End Sub
   Public Sub lt(ByVal a As Integer)
      Debug.WriteLine(" lt integer: " + a.ToString)
   End Sub

#If False Then
   Public Sub gt(Of T)(ByVal a As T)
      Debug.Fail("Not implemented")
   End Sub
   Public Sub lt(Of T)(ByVal a As T)
      Debug.Fail("Not implemented")
   End Sub
#End If
End Module
```

Comment: The issue isn't your declaration of `decision` but rather the calling method or class - please show us that. Your situation does not require generics, the overload you showed originally was fine.

Comment: added a working example that demonstrated the problem, the attached code as is will have the cannot convert error, changing `#if False Then` to `#If True Then` will always call the generic version.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it's also not the problem. Can you do some kind of *real* example?

Comment: unfortunately no. I don't like to post company code even though I know it's not going to cause any kind of harm I just never like to take the risk. I guess I am not sure what more is needed as the above code has the same problem I am experiencing else where, perhaps if you let me know what you're looking for I can provide more information. I have since come up with another way of solving my problem but since I've come across this issue twice I am now more interested in the provided example so I know how to address this in the future. I have a C++ version of the above code that works just fine.

Comment: Well... this situation should never need to be. If you have another fix, that's fine. But I can't help without the actual method and calling method.

Comment: I guess my main point would be: I could do this is C++, is there a VB.net is way to do something similar. Even if you can't I do appreciate you taking to time to read the question and responding to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx) (the same holds for VB .NET):

> C++ allows code that might not be valid for all type parameters in the
>   template, which is then checked for the specific type used as the type
>   parameter. C# requires code in a class to be written in such a way
>   that it will work with any type that satisfies the constraints. For
>   example, in C++ it is possible to write a function that uses the
>   arithmetic operators + and - on objects of the type parameter, which
>   will produce an error at the time of instantiation of the template
>   with a type that does not support these operators. C# disallows this;
>   the only language constructs allowed are those that can be deduced
>   from the constraints.

I'm not able to solve your problem with .NET Generics. But you can avoid repeating the logic by using lambdas and closures, which I also think is a more natural way to do it in .NET:

```
Public Sub Decision(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As Integer)
    Decision(b, Sub() gt(a), Sub() lt(a))
End Sub

Public Sub Decision(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
    Decision(b, Sub() gt(a), Sub() lt(a))
End Sub

Private Sub decision(ByVal b As Integer, ByVal gt As Action, ByVal lt As Action)
    If b > 10 Then
        gt()
    Else
        lt()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub gt(ByVal a As String)
    Debug.WriteLine(" gt string:  " + a)
End Sub
Public Sub gt(ByVal a As Integer)
    Debug.WriteLine(" gt integer: " + a.ToString)
End Sub

Public Sub lt(ByVal a As String)
    Debug.WriteLine(" lt string: " + a)
End Sub
Public Sub lt(ByVal a As Integer)
    Debug.WriteLine(" lt integer: " + a.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, my reason for using generics was to reduce the amount of duplicated code, in particular the logic branching code. It sounds like this will be the best I will be able to do. What version of .NET were lambdas introduced?

Comment: Lambdas were introduced in VB 9/VS2008 which was released with .NET 3.5. However, it's possible to set the target framework to .NET 2.0 (as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162235/953288).

Comment: Nice! I never though of using lambdas for this purpose. For what it's worth, an alternative which is probably close to what happens with C++ at runtime is to rely on a generic and branch depending on the type parameter (use `GetType(T)` via reflection). You however loose the strong-typing safeguards, as well as performance (reflection is said to be greedy).